# What are the possible causes for "The Dataflow appears to be stuck"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm following Google Cloud "Serverless Data Analysis with Google BigQuery and Cloud Dataflow" course on Coursera however the execution of the first lab on Dataflow fails with

```
(4ca2700be7a42d8b): Workflow failed. Causes: (4ca2700be7a420b8): The Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to the Dataflow team at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow.
```

This is the job https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow/job/2017-09-06_09_48_44-12392156033525406454?project=datatraining-178808

The code of the exercise is in `courses/data_analysis/lab2` folder of https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst. The lab project use dependency with range of version...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
        <version>[2.0.0-beta2,3.0.0)</version>
    </dependency>
```

Are 2.X.X versions compatible with current version of Dataflow? What are other possible causes of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try again - 2.1.0 temporarily had a bug in worker configuration, and because of this, your workers failed to start. I believe the bug has been fixed.

Comment: Thank you. It worked this time https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow/job/2017-09-07_23_36_20-1406641009476402242?project=datatraining-178808